# Including contents of a variable inside a Haml filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to make `article.content` filtered by :textile ?

```
 - @articles.each do |article|
    %article.post
      %header=article.name
      %p
        :textile 
          =article.content
      %footer
```

the output

```
<article class="post">
    <header>game</header>
    <p>
      </p><p>=article.content</p>
    <p></p>
    <footer></footer>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a Haml filter you use String interpolation to include Ruby code in your markup. For example:

```
require 'haml'                              
@x = 42                                               
Haml::Engine.new("%p= @x").render(self)              #=> "<p>42</p>\n"
Haml::Engine.new(":textile\n\t= @x").render(self)    #=> "<p>= @x</p>\n"
Haml::Engine.new(":textile\n\t\#{@x}").render(self)  #=> "<p>42</p>\n"

@content = "alpha\n\n#hi **mom**"
Haml::Engine.new(":textile\n\t\#{@content}").render(self)
#=> "<p>alpha</p>\n<p>#hi <b>mom</b></p>\n"
```

**Edit**: My previous answer was misleading with respect to newlines in the content, due to my flawed testing. As seen above, newlines in included content are handled fine directly.

As such, your Haml template should simply look like this:

```
- @articles.each do |article|
  %article.post
    %header=article.name
    :textile 
      #{article.content}
    %footer
```

Note that I've removed your `%p` tag surrounding your markup, as Textile introduces its own paragraph wrappers (even for single-line content).

Comment: @wizztjh My answer was wrong; please see the updated example above showing that it should 'just work' as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems fine, if everything else is getting rendered properly maybe it's a gem issue. Do you have RedCloth installed?

Edit: On second thought, what does the second line do? It might be the cause of your problem since I don't think %article.post is proper HAML syntax and the :textile filter is inside it

Comment: I think `%article.post` generates `<article class="post">`.